# How to return to an activity somewhere in the activity stack?

Tags: android, filter, android-activity, android-intent

Does somebody know if it is possible that an activity is removed from the activity stack if the device is out of memory? I have an activity A which calls the webbrowser and a webpage then calls an activity B which does something and then should return to activity A. Im using this intent with the flags..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, acticityToReturnTo.getClass());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

..to remove the webbrowser activity and activity B from the activity stack and return to activity A but it does not work. Its always a new instance of activity A which is created instead resuming to the already existing activity a instance. 
I dont want to use the single instance flag on activity A but this is the only solution currently working for me.. (Im developing for Android 1.6)

Maybe there is another solution to do what i want?

Answer (score 2):

Just try using

startActivityForResult(intent);

instead of

startActivity(intent);

Comment: hm didn't change anything for me :/ i bet its because of the webbrowser activity.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather think of it in terms of why its a problem to restart activity A, given that Activity A or B for that matter could be killed at any point during your operation.

Surely it would be better to make it such that you can return to Activity A regardless of the fact that you've either restarted it or re-created it from scratch, as there is no guarantee that this may not happen.

Comment: i think you're right its not a good design this way and i changed it now but nevertheless should it work with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag and i think it would save resources to reuse the existing activity (if it still exists)

Answer (score 0):

If the navigation is always A->B->A you could just call `finish()` on activity B and it'll return to activity A

Comment: no the navigation is A->external webbrowser->B->A and i think the broblem is that i cant remove the extermal webbrowser activity from the activity stack

Answer (score 0):

Are Browser and Activity A in the same task? You can check this by entering `adb shell dumpsys activity` in your console.

Comment: i use a normal uri intent to start the standart webbrowser so the browser not in the same task. does this matter?